# How to design a dynamic menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically, I'm making a google drive-esqe web app, that handles storage of user's notebooks and notes that are created in the app.

For my home screen, the user will see all of their notebooks rendered out and they will be clickable. When a user clicks on the item, the item highlights, as well as checking its respective checkbox (why we have both, I don't know.) and then a menu bar is supposed to appear at the top, giving the user options to perform upon that notebook/note.

The menu bar is par of a app-wide navigational bar, but the menu is strictly for the home page only.

The problem is in the functionality of some of the menu options. The way the app currently stands is that the user may select multiple items, but some menu options will disappear when doing so (e.g. Open will disappear as we only want one note opening at a time). I currently have no idea how to go about designing this. Mainly, I have no idea how to keep track of the number of highlighted items (will provide a snippet for the highlighting below), and no idea how to get the appropriate menu options to appear/disappear when appropriate. Right now, I have a menubar.ejs that holds all the menu titles, and it is included (<%-includemenubar.ejs %>) in the navigation bar that all screens have access too.

MenuBar.ejs

```
<ul class="menu">
<li><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Create</a></li>
<li><a href="/selectedNotebook">Open</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Download</a></li>
<li><a href="/share">Share</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
</ul>
```

Highlighting:

```
var itemSelect = function(){
$('.searchResult').click(function(){
$(this).toggleClass("highlighted");
var check= $(this).find('.checkbox');
check.prop('checked', !check.prop("checked"));
}
```

While this probably not the best way to go about this, its the only way I could think of at the time.

I'm really VERY new to all of these languages etc, so this is a pretty daunting task for me. Any help much appreciated! Hopefully I've provided enough information, but if I haven't, I'll do my best to specify more or add more where needed.

Answer (score 0):

To get all items which are highlighted you can use the jquery selector:

```
$('.highlighted'); // returns an array of hightlighted items
$('.highlighted').length; // number of highlighted items
```

The questions a little vague but in terms of designing, try to think of the app in terms of views/contexts, if I have a note open what should be able to see do?